# Video Header Autoplay Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a video header that autoplays on desktop when visited. It also autoplays on mobile but only on some mobile devices. I can't seem to figure out the issue. It currently autoplays on mobile on safari and chrome, iphone x and iphone 6 plus, but it doesnt auto play on a friends iphone x or another persons iphone 8 plus. Is browser version something i should look into? They seem to all be up to date. Or am i missing something in the code?

Here is the code for the video header:

```
 <video autoplay muted loop playsinline width="100%">
  <source src="{{ section.settings.videofile }}" type="video/mp4" id="{{ section.id }}">
 </video>
```

website: www.glamfleur.com

Answer (score 0):

videos anoy users you shouldn't use one instead convert the video into gif if you realy must however

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
//set autoplay
vid.autoplay = true;
//mute so autoplay has highest chance
vid.muted = true;
//loop so it dosn't end
vid.loop= true;
//reload so these effect
vid.load();
//play incase
vid.play();
```

```html
<video id='myVideo' src ='https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4'></video>
```